# Android ListView not found, causing either NullPointerException or Resource not Found

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, listadapter

I am trying to implement a ListView, inside a RelativeLayout. However when I call the setAdapter() function it claims that the ListView does not exist (but there are not compilation errors).

Below is the java code:

```
FrameLayout framecxpesq = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutSearch);
        ViewGroup janelapesquisa = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.janela_multisearch, null);
        ListView listapesquisa = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewOcorrencias);
        HashMap<String,String> mapaOcorrencias1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        mapaOcorrencias1.put("pagina", "pag 1");
        mapaOcorrencias1.put("resultados", "3 results found");
        HashMap<String,String> mapaOcorrencias2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        mapaOcorrencias2.put("pagina", "pag 7");
        mapaOcorrencias2.put("resultados", "15 resultados encontrados");
        HashMap<String,String> mapaOcorrencias3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        mapaOcorrencias3.put("pagina", "pag 9");
        mapaOcorrencias3.put("resultados", "10 asgsdgsdfge3333");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listamapas = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        listamapas.add(mapaOcorrencias1);
        listamapas.add(mapaOcorrencias2);
        listamapas.add(mapaOcorrencias3);


        if(tv_pesquisa.isSelected()){
            tv_pesquisa.setSelected(false);
            tv_pesquisa.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_icon);
            framecxpesq.removeAllViews();
        }
        else{
            tv_pesquisa.setSelected(true);
            tv_pesquisa.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_icon_sel);
            framecxpesq.addView(janelapesquisa);
            listapesquisa.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this,listamapas,R.layout.linha_ocorrencia,new String[]{"pagina","resultados"},new int[]{R.id.linha_item,R.id.linha_subitem}));

        }
```

Below is XML code. One XML file defines janela_multisearch, other contains the FrameLayout layoutSearch, in which the janela_multisearch is inserted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="320dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    layout="@layout/caixapesquisa" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/limparpag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/clean_page_selected"
    android:textColor="@color/cinza_escuro"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cancelar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/include1"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/cinza_escuro" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewOcorrencias"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/limparpag"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:background="@color/WHITE" >

</ListView>
```

The problem seems that linhapesquisa is not being found...
What is this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the ListView from its parent View, as the layout where it is defined is not set as the layout of the Activity. Only calling `findViewById()` will only search in the layout of the Activity.

```
ViewGroup janelapesquisa = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.janela_multisearch, null);
ListView listapesquisa = (ListView) janelapesquisa.findViewById(R.id.listViewOcorrencias);
```

Same with the other Views that are in this Layout.